# Choosing a primary key for many-many relation

Tags: sql, database, database-design, primary-key

I'm trying to model a site similar to StackOverflow. It has a set of users and questions, and user vote on questions. Each user can only have one vote on each question.

What should the structure of my "VotesOnQuestions" table look like:

1. Should I have an auto-generated "VoteID" column?
2. How do I disallow, at the schema level, a user from having multiple votes on a question?
3. Should I, instead of a VoteID column, just use (UserID, QuestionID) as a primary key?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843222/do-link-tables-need-a-meaningless-primary-key-field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Primary Key **UserID, QuestionID**.

That will enforce your requirement, and optimze searches.

Comment: although, I like user_id and question_id, personally